# Azure DataFactory pass Global Parameter to PipeLine or dataSet

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a global parameter in place, say GP_UserName that I want to use in a Linked Service.

I understand cannot be done directly (not sure why that should be so as all other incarnations of Global Parameters are, well, global) but via Global Parameters -> Pipeline -> DataSet - > Linked Service.

I can create parameters in the pipeline, pass them to the dataset (dynamic content), and then pass them to the linked service (dynamic content).  But how do I get the pipeline to use the global parameter?  I have created a pipeline parameter but they do not allow dynamic content to be used.

I have seen posted solutions on here that says that the global parameter can be accessed in the dataset, but they cannot.  The dynamic editor in the dataset does not have access to global parameters, and trying to force it just results in an error.

The Microsoft post just says Global parameter -> Pipeline - > dataset -> linked server, but lacks an example of this actually happening.

So how do I inject my global parameter into a pipeline parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global Parameters are parameters which consist of a **constant value that can be used by a *Pipeline***. This means that they can be used inside any pipeline, but not outside the pipeline such as Dataset creation, Linked service creation etc.

To use global Parameters to create a linked service, you need to do it via `Global parameter -> Pipeline - > dataset -> linked service`. The following is an example of how you can do this.

- First create your linked service. In this demo I am creating a linked service to *Azure data lake gen2* called `datalake_source`. In this, create a parameter (**named `url_ls` whose value will be given from pipeline via global parameter**), choose `Enter Manually` as account selection method and give the URL as `@{linkedService().url_ls}`

[image]

- Create the pipeline. I used `Get metadata` activity for example. Create the dataset. After selecting `datalake_source` as the linked service, go to advanced and open the dataset.

[image]

- Create a parameter **inside dataset** called `url_ds` whose value will be passed from pipeline (`Get Metadata` activity) using global parameter under `Dataset Properties`.

[image]

- Inside dataset, under linked service properties, give the value for `url_ls` as `@dataset().url_ds`

[image]

- Now running the pipeline give the required output.

[image]

Using global parameters in Linked service has to be done using `Global parameter -> Pipeline - > dataset -> linked service` because:

- A pipeline can use pipeline parameters (local and global), a dataset can use dataset parameters and a linked service can use linked service parameters.
- You cannot use Global Parameters in dataset or linked service, **they need to be passed from the pipeline**.
- Hence you create a global parameter (which can be used in linked service), use it in pipeline to pass its value to dataset via dataset parameter (`url_ds`), pass dataset parameter value (`url_ds`) to linked service parameter (`url_ls`) which can be referenced using dynamic content in Linked service.

Comment: Thanks for that, very detailed explanation.  Had everything was just missing the get metadata activity to obtain the global parameter.

Comment: The activity that you use might vary (I used `get metadata as an example`), but the procedure will be exactly the same. Which ever activity you use (does not have to be `get metadata`), you will be passing the global parameter value to a dataset parameter (as shown in 3rd image), proceed from there and use it in linked service.